# How can i use associative array name @type in Handlebars?

Tags: javascript, web, handlebars.js

Is it possible to use `{{@type}}` in a way without deactivating `@data` in Handlebars?

Dataexample:

```
var data = {"@type" : "test"}
```

Is there an escape such as `{{\@type}}` or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Just using helpers:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("escape", function(obj, name) {
    return obj[name];
});
```

And then just use

```
{{escape this "@type"}}
```